# Remove shadows between two navigation items

Tags: jquery, html, css, shadow

I tried to create a navigation menu, but have one problem with.

So that is my HTML:

```
<div id="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">fd</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">vc</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ew</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ds</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">vcx</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">re</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The CSS file is on codepen project, because it is too big. The problem is with two closest menu items, when one of it is active and another one with applied hover. How is it possible to fix it? i mean to remove shadows between them.

http://cdpn.io/asjde

Comment: paste the hover css code

Comment: Have you tried using CSS sibling selectors?

Comment: @Swervo, Box shadows are not individually (top, bottom, left, right) adjustable currently in CSS3, hence sibbling parameters won't work here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want no box shadow in your navigations simply remove this from your css and it eliminates the shadows on the nav.

```
box-shadow: inset -4px 0 7px -5px black, inset 4px 0 7px -5px black;
```